# Outputting a link as a button in node.tpl.php

Tags: nodes

I am trying to rewrite the output of node.tpl.php.

I am using field link. I cannot figure out how to get the field to render as a button. I did find that the field is output as an array

I tried this but it just makes the link just a link to the page I am on:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" href="<?php print render ($content[field_amazon_link][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['display_url']); ?>">Buy Now</a>
```

The devel module gives me this info. Keep in mind php is my week area. This is my first time rewriting a node file as I used to have a helper and he has moved on.

field_amazon_link (Array, 1 element)

```
0 (Array, 5 elements)
    url (String, 142 characters ) https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZGUBN3C/re...
    title (String, 83 characters ) https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZGUBN3C/re...
    attributes (Array, 1 element)
    html (Boolean) FALSE
    display_url (String, 83 characters ) https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZGUBN3C/re...
```

And this is from the object devel tool
 field_amazon_link (Array, 1 element)

```
und (Array, 1 element)
    0 (Array, 5 elements)
        url (String, 142 characters ) https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZGUBN3C/re...
        title (String, 83 characters ) https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZGUBN3C/re...
        attributes (Array, 1 element)
        html (Boolean) FALSE
        display_url (String, 83 characters ) https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZGUBN3C/re..
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what ultimately worked for me. I don't really understand it completely, but if anyone can shed some light on why it worked, I would really like to know.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" target="_blank" href="<?php print $content['field_amazon_link']['#items']['0']['url']; ?>">Buy Now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The gist of it is to add the correct classes `btn btn-danger btn-lg` to the array before rendering it. You could accomplish it like this, with in a '.tpl.php' file:

```
<?php
  $content['field_amazon_link']['#items']['0']['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn';
  $content['field_amazon_link']['#items']['0']['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-danger';
  $content['field_amazon_link']['#items']['0']['attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-lg';
?>
```

Then you can use the Drupal API to render it to HTML using the *render* function the whole, and print it, like so:

```
<?php print render($content['field_amazon_link']); ?>
```

Comment: @tHaKaREe, I didn't get to test this code, i will do when i have a chance. Also, I would like to provide some alternative implementations.

Comment: I appreciate the help either way. Thanks. Got it working with my above solution I found